Reattaching loose pieces of aluminum siding
I bought a house with a few loose aluminum sidings. Gave a try and at using a siding removal tool to attach but wasn't making any progress. Was I not using enough elbow grease or is this not the right tool for the job?
https://imgur.com/a/NCF6IKN


FYI, that's probably steel siding. I have yet to see aluminum siding that looks like that (though I had a smooth single 8" aluminum on my 1950s home, presumably installed in the 70s).

Siding removal tools allow you to disengage the bottom flange from the panel below by pulling downward. You simply need to stretch the panel below the one below it and then push or tap it upward to snap in place. It really is that simple. Don't use a hammer directly on the siding. Use a wooden block at least 12" long to distribute force and prevent dents.
If the problem is that the panel wasn't stretched enough during installation, so that there's no tension on the installed panel, try to compress it vertically by over-folding the interior bends a bit. The alternative is to take the whole wall down and reinstall it with more tension.

But can't the siding tool be used for the stretching?
